# RecyclerView wraps its conent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I am using the RecyclerView to inflate a Linear Vertical listViews, However, although the width of a child is set to match_parent, RecyclerView wraps that at runtime.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

**item_recyclerView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tag_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:maxLines="2"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tag_role"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_pic"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:rotation="-45"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.circleImageView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:layout_weight="1"` on your first `LinearLayout` of `item_recyclerView` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inflating a layout file, the `layout_` attributes on the root view will be ignored unless you specify a parent `ViewGroup` in the `inflate()` call. You are not currently doing so.

In your `onCreateViewHolder()` method, replace this:

> ```
> ItemQuestionPostBinding binding = ItemQuestionPostBinding.inflate(inflater);
> ```

with this:

```
ItemQuestionPostBinding binding = ItemQuestionPostBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
```

---

Note also that you probably don't want to be using `match_parent` for the *height* of your RecyclerView's items:

> ```
> android:layout_width="match_parent"
> android:layout_height="match_parent"
> ```

This will give the appearance that only a single item is visible in your RecyclerView, since each item will be the full height of the screen. This is currently not a problem for the exact same reason that the `match_parent` width is being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

give for your parent linearlayout weightSum  5
give for imageView weight 1 and do his width  0
and for child linearlayout weight 4

```
enter code here
```